# How do i download a zip with multiple types of files with axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

In my vueJs application i have the following axios POST api call that is suppose to return multiple files that i wish to save on a .zip folder. however when i use the following axios method i can't open my zip and an error occurs saying that "my folder.zip is invalid".

How do i properly download the response.data?

Here is the method. I send a few needed information in my raw call body and a file that is needed to be uploaded so i can get the other files that i need to download.

```
upload() {
      console.log("uploading")
      let formData = new FormData();
      let gerarMenus = "on";
      let zipName= "test";
      let var1= "on";
      let var2= "on";
      let var3= "on";
      let var4= "on";
       this.files.forEach((f,x) => {
         formData.append('file'+(x+1), f);

       });
       formData.append('zipName', zipName);
         formData.append('var1', var1);
         formData.append('var2', var2);
         formData.append('var3', var3);
         formData.append('var4', var4);

       axios
         .post("/myUrl/downloadFile", formData)
         .then((response) => {
           console.log(response.data)
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response]));
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = url;
            link.setAttribute('download', zipName+ '.zip');
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click()}
            ).catch(e => {
          console.error(e);
        });
```

EDIT: I tried tony19's answer but i still get the same error.
Not sure if it is any help but i am suppose to get multiple xml and sql files.

EDIT2: here's a print of response.data in my console.log():
[image]

Comment: can you post a sample of `response.data` please ?

Comment: i've updated the question with a print of response.data

Comment: So the api call doesn't return an array of files, it returns the binary for the actual `.zip` file, is that correct ?

Comment: i think so, yeah. At least it is what is showing to me here.

Comment: try adding the `mime-type` like : `window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/zip'}));`

Comment: i just tried it but it didnt work, i got the same error

Comment: Can you also post the headers of your request ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set a `responseType` option to `blob` in your request:

```
axios
     .post("/myUrl/downloadFile", formData, {
          responseType: 'blob'
     })
```

And use `response.data` in a Blob constructor as @tony19 already mentioned.

Comment: hwy, it worked.
why did that work though, is responseType a header?

Comment: no, it is just an axios parameter by default it gets a response body as string, source code link https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/2ee3b482456cd2a09ccbd3a4b0c20f3d0c5a5644/lib/adapters/xhr.js#L49

Comment: @Otorrinolaringologista-man, sorry for incorrect info - `responseType` is a XMLHttpRequest field which axios just proxies

Answer (score 6):

In this line:

```js
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response])); // DON'T DO THIS
                                                 ^^^^^^^^
```

...you're creating an object URL to a blob of the entire [Axios response object](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) (including HTTP status code, headers, etc.), but you actually want the `data` property within it like this:

```js
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
```

Comment: alright. ill test it out at work tomorrow morning. thanks a bunch.