# Download multiple files via Axios and .zip them

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, zip

I am trying to expose a .zip in VueJS containing multiple files that are stored in a remote server.
I have tried at least with just one .csv file: the download works, but opening the archive fails because the .zip is recognised as invalid.

What I have tried to do is, this following [this previous  issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57437531/how-do-i-download-a-zip-with-multiple-types-of-files-with-axios):

```
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(download_url, {
      responseType:'blob'
    });
    
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data));
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute("download", "filename.zip");
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

That allows me to download the .zip, but again, it is invalid and I cannot open it.

Then, I would like to be able to do it with multiple "download_urls", i.e. with multiple files in the same .zip, but for now I would be happy to succeed at least with one file!

Thank you in advance with your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let the link () be directly what you are getting from axios (axios.get(url))
2. To download multiple file in one zip you could let the server pack them and provide public link to download (we can elaborate on this if you need to)
3. Again use that public link from the server to download the zip
4. [image]
   Use `download_url` and put it in a

Comment: Thank you a lot @babacar for your response. Could you explain it more explicitly?

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if you need more help